# Emacs-Lisp mode indentation problem when doc string contains left parenthesis in first column

Tags: indentation, emacs-lisp-mode

Usually when I write Lisp code (in an Emacs-Lisp mode buffer), I can press `TAB` (bound to `indent-for-tab-command`) to indent code properly. However, if I write a `defun` with a docstring (longer than one line) that also contains a left parenthesis (in the first column), `TAB` stops working for the given `defun`. For example:

```
(defun test ()
  "Hello
(ok) xxx."

nil)
```

If I put cursor on `n` in `nil` and press `TAB` I would expect `nil` to be indented 2 places, but it does not work ( unless I remove the left parenthesis `(` from the first column on the second line of the docstring).

I am using Emacs 25.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Put ``\`` (backslash) in front of the parenthesis.

Comment: Seems to be linked to `calculate-lisp-indent` in `lisp-mode.el`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR `(setq open-paren-in-column-0-is-defun-start nil)`

The docstring for `indent-for-tab-command` tells us it calls the function in variable `indent-line-function`.  In emacs-lisp mode this is `lisp-indent-line`, defined in `lisp-mode.el`.  We can see in the source code that it calls `calculate-lisp-indent`.  `M-x trace`ing these two functions, both with and without the offending `(` at first col and looking at `calculate-lisp-indent` source code, I saw the call to `beginning-of-defun`.  Tried with with `M-: (beginning-of-defun)` w/ and w/o the `(` in first col showed this was relevant.  Then the docstring says:

> beginning-of-defun is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `lisp.el'.
>
> [...]
>
> When `open-paren-in-column-0-is-defun-start' is non-nil, a defun
>   is assumed to start where there is a char with open-parenthesis
>   syntax at the beginning of a line.

I suspect `beginning-of-defun` to at least be slower then.

EDIT: as found at by @Häkon Hægland this is actually discussed in [Chapter 26.2.1 : Left Margin Convention](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Left-Margin-Paren.html) of the Emacs manual.

Comment: Thanks for digging this out! Also see [Chapter 26.2.1 : Left Margin Convention](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Left-Margin-Paren.html) in the Emacs manual.